# 'gzip decompression failed' and 'tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors'

Tags: terminal, png, gzip, tar, unzip

## Mac OS

I have a file, images.tar.gz. , which contains about 7000 .png images. I need to unzip this file.

But when I use terminal to unzip it

`tar zxvf /Users/JourneyWoo/images_002.tar.gz`

I always encounter this problem

```
... ...   
x images/00003910_000.png
x images/00001934_002.png
x images/00002250_001.png: gzip decompression failed
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

In this way, I cannot get the whole dataset in this .tar.gz file due to the break.
I also used `chmod u+r /Users/JourneyWoo/images_002.tar.gz`, but it did not work.

Maybe the problem about one of the png images in this .tar.gz file? How can I deal with this problem?
REALLY THANKS!

Comment: It sounds more like the gzip file itself is corrupt.

Comment: @molbdnilo Since this gzip file contains 7000 images, and it seems that only a few images are corrupt. Do you have any methods that can exclude the effect of those damaged images and make this unzipping process move on?

Comment: gzip and tar don't care about what the archive contains. In particular, they are completely unaware of the concept of "image". Is the size of the archive reasonable for 7000 binary files? If you downloaded it from somewhere, it may have been truncated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is corrupted. You need to try to get a good copy from wherever it came from, or if it was corrupted when created, you need to get it regenerated from the images. The problem has nothing to do with the .png files. The problem is that the .tar.gz is corrupted.

(By the way "unzip" is the wrong verb here, since it is not a zip file. "extract" would be the correct verb.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 8):

The problem lies in the fact that Mac OS uses bsdtar. When I have a similar problem, I installed gnutar (most Linux systems use ).

```
brew install gnu-tar
gtar -ztvf archive.tar.gz
```

Comment: Irrelevant. Whatever tar was being used has no problem with the tar file format, since many files are properly extracted. The problem, as stated explicitly in the error message, is that the gzip file is corrupted.

Comment: I would like to note that this worked for me on Mac, and my file was not corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

So this fails on a Mac (Ventura) using a tar pipeline.  And it indeed is bsdtar.  Trying to transfer entire home directory including all the weird files in Library.  Saw the usual messages about sockets and the like but could not figure out which file this message might apply to.  Not listing file names during the transfer.

This kept failing in random places.  As root.  What finally worked?  cpio! It still had weird failures for individual files, but it copied all but 100 files of 220k.

```
# cd source-directory
# find . -depth -print | cpio -pdm /destination
```